# ECEF to J2000 using skyfield

Tags: python, skyfield

Say I have (ECEF) latitude, longitude and distance to Earth for an object at certain time. I need to get J2000 coordinates of it.
What I'm doing is

```
import skyfield.api
planets = skyfield.api.load('de421.bsp')
earth = planets['earth']
ts = skyfield.api.load.timescale()
sat = earth + skyfield.api.Topos(latitude_degrees=latitude, longitude_degrees=longitude)
obs = earth.at(ts.utc(time)).observe(sat)
x, y, z = obs.km
```

Then, I would normalize `[x, y, z]` and multiply it by the distance to Earth.
There are two questions involved:

1. Is it correct to do that?
2. Is there a faster method without loading 'de421.bsp'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result should be accurate, but there is indeed an easier way — your hunch that you should ask was indeed correct here! Try reading through the “Generating a satellite position” section of the Earth satellite documentation:

http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/earth-satellites.html#generating-a-satellite-position

I think you will find that you can do something like this to achieve the same result:

```
sat = skyfield.api.Topos(latitude_degrees=latitude, longitude_degrees=longitude)
x, y, z = sat.at(ts.utc(time)).position.km
```

But I am not sure exactly how your code will look, since I don't see anywhere in your code the distance-to-Earth that you spoke of, and your code references a `sa` variable that isn't otherwise used (maybe you meant `sat`?) — but hopefully the documentation will get you moving!

Comment: that's perfect, many thanks! `sa` is indeed `sat` (fixing it). And the distance to earth would be used at the end, multiplying the result so it gets the correct distance (anyway, this part was not so important, that's why I omitted it).